# PHP Syntax Error: mysqli_stmt_bind_param()

Tags: php, mysqli

I've never worked with PHP and am powering through this code in order to get my Android device to store three variables on a web server. My error is coming from the last line of the following piece of code:

```
$name = $_POST[“name”];
$password = $_POST[“password”];
$username = $_POST[“username”];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 'INSERT INTO `user`(name,username,password) VALUES(?,?,?)');

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, “sss”, $name, $username, $password);
```

My file name is Register.php and the error is:

> Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home/a9208046/public_html/Register.php on line 11

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: Use an IDE (or even a basic text editor) to work on PHP files.  Don't use MS Word or LibreOffice or any "word processor".  I say that because your code is littered with "smart quotes".  Replace the `“`/`”` with *normal* quotes `"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using smart quotes `“`; if you had proper error-reporting you would see:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant “sss” - assumed '“sss”' in /in/MnZR4 on line 3
```

This explains the problem; what you intend to be a 3 character string ends up being 5 characters, hence the error. Use normal quotes and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, “sss”, $name, $username, $password);
```

It should be 'sss' instead of "sss"

Comment: instead of `“sss”`, i.e. instead of `{Left Double Quotation Mark=U+201C}sss{Right Double Quotation Mark=U+201D} ` - simple double quotes (U+0022) would be ok.